# Tailwind applying extra classes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I've inherited this project and iDo you have an idea why tailwind is re-applying a style that should be ignored by screen size?

Having this button:

```
<div className="flex h-[40px] w-full items-center justify-center place-self-center rounded-full bg-[#2B9355] md:w-[175px]">
 <button className="font-poppins text-[15px] font-bold text-white">
  Siguiente paso
 </button>
</div>
```

With this, it should be full width on mobile and width: 175px from medium size and above.
But it is reacting as the picture, it's re-adding w-full with more priority. This is the only place this is happening, i solve it before and i've been working with tailwind for some time, but i'm not getting this.

I've already disabled all extensions just in case.
Something weird that i've found is that i'm having this issue on console

```
Warning: Extra attributes from the server: role,class
at ion-icon
at ReactComponent (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@ionic/react/dist/index.js:692:13)
at IonIcon
at IonIconContainer (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/@ionic/react/dist/index.js:1805:9)
at IonIcon
```

Not sure if this has any responsibility on this.
Any help will be appreaciated.

This is running with

- next@13.4.1
- postcss@8.4.31
- tailwindcss@3.3.3

[image]

Comment: Hello @ValenciaHQ! How are you? I don't see any error in your React code, and the problem does not look familiar to me. Do you have the error or something to try to help you?

Comment: No errors at all, it's just 'adding' that class. It may be some global class or something, i will keep looking

Comment: I'm running into this same issue right now with ion-icon. When I inspect element I see both className and class, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact thing, and it turns out the `ion-icon` component needs to have a regular `class` and not `className`.

For me, it was this before:

```
<ion-icon
    className="w-20 h-20 md hydrated"
    name="warning"
    role="img"
    aria-label="checkmark outline"
></ion-icon>
```

and after:

```
<ion-icon
    class="w-20 h-20 md hydrated"
    name="warning"
    role="img"
    aria-label="checkmark outline"
></ion-icon>
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! This case we are using this import { IonIcon } from "@ionic/react"; so seems that is encapsulated within it, but i will follow that approach.